# Google cloud sql: How to import postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I have a Postgresql database that is running on premises which I want to import into Google Cloud SQL. My database is called `test` and is owned by user `test`

Steps I've taken:

1. created Cloud SQL instance
2. created database on Cloud SQL instance:

   curl --header "Authorization: Bearer XXXXX" \
   --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data '{"project": "YYYYYY", "instance": "dev", "name": "test"}' \

   https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/YYYYYY/instances/dev/databases -X POST
3. Created `test` user:

   `gcloud beta sql users create test host --instance=dev --password=test`
4. Dumped DB from source db with `pg_dump`
5. Tried to restored ... got this error:
   `ERROR: must be member of role test`

So how do I execute import under `test` user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer my own question...

Just use `--no-acl --no-owner` with `pg_dump` to remove all ownership altering, and it will work.